# How to see the limit of the integral $\int_0^r(\alpha^{-1}\sinh(\alpha t))^{n-1}dt$ when $r\to\infty$?

Tags: calculus

How do we see that
$$\int_0^r(\alpha^{-1}\sinh(\alpha t))^{n-1}dt\sim \frac{\exp((n-1)\alpha r)}{(n-1)(2\alpha)^n}$$ when $r\to\infty$?

Comment: By definition, $sinh(\alpha r)= \frac {e^{\alpha r}-e^{-\alpha r}}{2}$ behaves like $e^{\alpha r}$ when $r$ is large. By substituting in the integral, you get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by writing $$\sinh(x)=\frac{\exp(x)-\exp(-x)}{2}$$ Both terms start from 1, but the second term goes to 0, while the first term increases "exponentially" :). So the farther we go with the integration limit, the positive exponent will dominate
$$\int_0^r(\alpha^{-1}\sinh(\alpha t))^{n-1} dt \sim \int_0^r((2\alpha)^{-1}\exp(\alpha t))^{n-1} dt$$
Note that the constant term is much smaller than the exponent at $r$